# Photos being stored on Amazon S3 bucket through Java's AWS SDK gain 1 pixel in height

Tags: java, swift, image, amazon-s3, base64

I've encountered this strange issue while trying to transfer images from my Java webserver to my Amazon S3 bucket. I am developing a mobile application for both Android and iOS (with Swift), which allows users to upload images from their device to the server.

The images (Bitmaps for Android, and UIImage for iOS) are both converted to Base 64 before being sent to my webserver (made in Java to conform to HTTP/1.1 standards). The data arrives to the server intact (meaning by printing the base 64 before it is sent, and after it arrives to the server, they are identical). From there I decode the String into a byte array. I have isolated the issue to have something to do with the actual sending process to the Amazon S3 bucket. Take the following snippet for example:

```
//image is a byte array, and imageid a String
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
meta.setContentType("image/jpeg");
meta.setContentLength(image.length);
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucket", "images/" + imageid + ".jpg", is, meta));
```

This code works fine for Android, where the images upload at 1080x1080 without an issue. However, when I try to upload an image from iPhone, the resolution becomes 1080x1081. Confused by this, I decided to try saving the image locally as well as send it to the server using ImageIO. Strangely enough, using:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image));
File f = new File("image.jpg"); //Removed file creation for brevity
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
```

When I used the "identify" command from Imagick on the local image, the output is:

```
image.jpg JPEG 1080x1080 1080x1080+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 53.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

However when I transfer the image from the S3 bucket and do the same thing, I get:

```
image2.jpg JPEG 1080x1081 1080x1081+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 56.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Again, this only occurs with uploads from iOS. The image itself is still valid and opens without an issue. For example:

[Face Down Camera Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RrU3.jpg)

(Picture was taken while the camera was facing down, hence the dark image)

I suspect the issue may have something to do with differences in how the images are encoded into Base 64. I use the [Bouncycastle](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/util/encoders/Base64.html) library to do the encoding on Android, as well as the decoding on the webserver, and use an NSData function in swift as described below:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(normImg, 0.4)
let base64 = NSString(data: imageData!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
```

What confuses me the most is how ~3KB of data (which makes sense for 1080 extra pixels at 3 bytes per RGB pixel) seems to just be appearing out of nowhere, and why it seems to be isolated to iOS.

Hopefully I was clear enough with my question and the debugging I have done to provide as much information as possible. If you need any more information, please let me know!

**Edit:** Just ran a test and uploaded a 1080x1080 image by command line to the S3 bucket. It also adds the extra pixels.

**Edit2:** Decided to change how the file uploading process worked. It is no longer being converted to base 64, and the NSData of the UIImage is being converted into a byte (UInt8) array and uploaded. The still leads to the same result of having the extra pixel, which rules out my original speculation that it had something to do with the base64 encoding. Android still seems to function properly on the other hand, which leaves me to believe that the binary data of the image is not completely valid for whatever reason. I believe the EXIF data is formatted differently between Android and iOS, though I don't know what would cause this.